# Is there any way to support compatibility view for IE from Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to support **compatibility view** for IE browser. But, the angular application will no work when I try to turn on compatibility view on IE.

I want to know is there any way to run angular application under compatibility view?

[image]

As I understand Angular 8 will not support compatibility view. I read this from here (https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

I observed that whenever I turn on **compatibility view** on IE. The browser will change to default version which is 7. So, I think maybe there is a way to make Angular run well on IE 7 then it will support **compatibility view**.